# How to log the value of a clone drop down?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, clonenode

I understand that when you change a selection, the state of the selection is stored in browser and the cloned node will never include the state of object/ element which is changed and/or stored by browser. But for input, it is stored as a value of the attribute value and get cloned. When I am having trouble with is how do I clone the selected value. I seen other solutions that really complex I am just trying to get the select value and log it into the console. No append into the body, no crazy cloning with lots of divs. Just getting the selected value and logging it.

```js
document.getElementById("buttonTest").addEventListener("click", cloneIt);

function cloneIt() {
  const origSelect = document.querySelector("select");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(origSelect));
  var e = document.getElementById("OBJ_TYPE");
  console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text);
  let cloneThis = document.getElementById("cloneThis");
  let clonedNode = cloneThis.cloneNode(true);
  clonedNode.querySelector("select").value = origSelect.value;
}

cloneIt();
```

```html
<button id="buttonTest" title="Test" style="visibility: visible; background-color: #f6f6f6; font-weight: bold;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                    Test</button>
<div id="cloneThis">
  <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
    <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="newstepselect">
      <option value="TP">TP</option>
      <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
      <option value="Package">Package</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</div>
```

Comment: unclear what your problem is. You are setting the value with the commented out line....

Comment: Sorry it been updated when I was testing it I tried commenting it out same issue though. Essentially when I have this drop down I can get the value but when I clone it and than try to get the value it keeps going back to the default value instead of the selected value.

Comment: You are making a clone of the element. You are not adding it to the DOM. The value is going to be what you set it to, it is not going to update to the value of the one you cloned it from. Maybe I am misunderstanding it still.

Comment: You pretty much nail it. My question is there a way to get the selected value from the clone element since it is not being added to the DOM? I have a project that clones id like OBJ_TYPE and I need the value from the selected clone drop down.

Comment: The value is never going to change from what you set it to. Are you expecting it somehow mimics the parent??

Comment: Well I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446051/why-does-the-value-of-a-select-element-reset-when-using-clonenode and was wondering if there was a way I could something similar. All I need is to be able to selectindex the clone element drop down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252237/discussion-between-genericdude76-and-epascarello).