# Cloning node along with dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I need to clone a dropdown and text box along with its values and append to next line on clicking of a button.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="mynode">
<span class="label">If value: </span> <select class="options">
<option>more than</option> <option>below than</option> <option>same</option>
</select>
<span class="label">Temperature: </span> <input text="number" value="55" />
</div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="myBtn">Add Row</button>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListenet('click', function() {
    const container = document.querySelectorAll(".mynode");
    const mynode = container[container.length-1];
    const latest = mynode.cloneNode(true);
    document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(latest);
});
```

In JS, I am copying the last row of the container and appending it correctly. But if I modify values in dropdown, then the new row is not having the updated selected value. How to solve this? I need to modify only JS code not the HTML. Also I don't want to use jquery or other libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the value of a <select> element reset when using cloneNode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446051/why-does-the-value-of-a-select-element-reset-when-using-clonenode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the node itself, but not its value. Also, there's a typo: you need to use addEventListener instead of addEventListenet. This is the corrected code (HTML is not changed, as requested):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const container = document.querySelectorAll(".mynode");
    const mynode = container[container.length - 1];
    const latest = mynode.cloneNode(true);

    const originalDropdown = mynode.querySelector('.options');
    const clonedDropdown = latest.querySelector('.options');
    clonedDropdown.value = originalDropdown.value;

    document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(latest);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="mynode">
<span class="label">If value: </span> <select class="options">
<option>more than</option> <option>below than</option> <option>same</option>
</select>
<span class="label">Temperature: </span> <input text="number" value="55" />
</div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="myBtn">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Good answer. I'm surprised that the text field's value is copied, but not the dropdown. It seems the browser doesn't update the DOM attribute when you select a dropdown value...